# Microsoft SMO for .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am creating a setup project for a product.  For my install, I have an executable that is run as a custom action.  This executable is responsible for executing a SQL script during the install.  However the SMO is giving me the following error:

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime
```

Most responses from google have told me to put the following in my app.config file, which I did but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Anybody have any solutions.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of SMO (SQL Server 2008 R2 SDK)?

Comment: I believe so but I can give that a shot.